# Text formatting in for loop with Python

Tags: python, text, formatting

I am trying to pull information for my system drives. The issue I am having is being able to split the information up and put it where it needs to go. Below is the desired out put if there is more than one volume:

```
Mountpoint: C:\
OS Volume: True
GUID: d1dd2893f42711e09090806e6f6e6963

Mountpoint: D:\
OS Volume: False
GUID: b4584ed2e3b211e2ae7d806e6f6e6963
```

Below is the information that prints out when I run what I currently have:

```
Mountpoint: C:\
                Mountpoint: D:\

OS Volume: True
                OS Volume: False

GUID: d1dd2893f42711e09090806e6f6e6963
                GUID: b4584ed2e3b211e2ae7d806e6f6e6963
```

I know what I am doing wrong, I am not sure how to fix it. I have looked through the interwebs to no avail. It might just be my naivety.

Here is the code I am using:

```
def driveInfo(agent):
    info = "info " + agent + " | grep "
    drives = subprocess.Popen(info + "'\[mountpoints\]'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    drives, err = drives.communicate()
    strdrives = str(drives)

    ### Volume Information
    mount = subprocess.Popen(info + "'\[mountpoints\]'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    osvol = subprocess.Popen(info + "'\[OSVolume\]'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    guid = subprocess.Popen(info + "'\[guid\]'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    ### Communicate calls
    mount, err = mount.communicate()
    osvol, err = osvol.communicate()
    guid, err = guid.communicate()

    ### String conversions
    mount = str(mount).strip()
    osvol = str(osvol).strip()
    guid = str(guid).strip()

    ### Drive Information Output
    for drive in strdrives:
            print mount
            print osvol
            print guid

driveInfo(agent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drive `variable` is iterating over the content of `strdrives`. However, inside your loop, your using independant variables (`mount, osvol, guid`)

If you have more than one entry in strdrives, expected result would be duplicated blocks of text
=> most probably, your variables don't contain what you expect (and thus your split was not workinjg as expected, you didn't provide it however)

Comment: Bruce, I have edited my original question to make things a little more clear. The "agent" variable can be ignored for all intents and purposes of the question